# Add 2 Characters to char array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a problem about how to add 2 characters inside char array , I dont know where is the problem , but I want to add after each 'c' and 'd' any character like 'A' , but It not work correctly , I mean if input is "abcde" It Shows the output like this "abcdeA",
and if the input "abcdecde",It shows "abcdecdedA",but I want to be like this "abcdAecdAe",can help me , this is my code.

```
void StrAdd_A_afterEach_CD(char *p1){
    char s[100];
    char *p2 = &s[0];
    int c1=0,c2=0;
    while(*p1!='\0')
    {
        if(*p1++=='c')
            if(*p1=='d')
            {
                p1--;
                *p2++ = *p1++;
                *p2++ = *p1++;
                *p2 = 'A';
                p2++;
                c1++;
            }   
        else 
        {
            p1--;p1--;
            *p2 = *p1;
            p1++;p2++;
            c2++;
        }

    }
    *p2 = '\0';
    p2-=(c2+c1);
    p1-=c2;

    while(*p2!='\0')
    {
        *p1 = *p2;
        p1++;p2++;
    }
    *p1 = '\0';
}

int main(){

    char s1[100];
    gets(s1);
    StrAdd_A_afterEach_CD(&s1[0]);
    cout<<s1;

    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I dont want to change the function to any return type , like char on *func. or to do it with function , because I'm learning basics, but Help me please to correct that code,and thanks.

Comment: Use a `std::vector` and that entire **mess** goes away.

Comment: Why are you even doing this the C way? C++ can act like C, but it exists for a reason.

Comment: thanks for help,but I dont want the vector because I didn't learned it till now,I want like C++,without using functions or vectors,and without changing 'void',thanks

Comment: So what you're saying is instead of learning how to use `std::vector` you prefer to implement it in an asinine hard to maintain way? Mmmm-kay.

Comment: yes but I think there is a little mistake in my code but where I dont know, I do Other Example like that,'to add one char after char',and'add one after 2 char',but this..I dont know,It's confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. At least a problem that you're doing wrong is that you are changing the address of parameter p1, and you don't store the initial address that's why you append the A.
2. You're not adding all the chars into the s string

Hope the code bellow helps.

```
void StrAdd_A_afterEach_CD(char *param)
{
    char* p1 = param;

    char s[100] = {0};
    char *p2 = s;

    while( *p1 )
    {
        bool processed = false;
        if(*p1 == 'c')
        {
            if(*(p1+1)=='d')
            {
                processed = true;

                *p2++ = *p1++;
                *p2++ = *p1++;
                *p2++ = 'A';
            }
        }
        if( ! processed )
        {
            *p2++ = *p1++;
        }

    }
    *p2 = '\0';

    // the following block is = strcpy(param, s);
    {
        p2 = s;
        while (*p2)
        {
            *param++ = *p2++;
        }

        *param = '\0';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks,sir that help me.Now I learned How to do that,The Problem was finished,Thank you again.Regards.